# Properties of a Matrix that is generated by normally distributed random numbers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, normal-distribution

I am working with the *randn* function in MATLAB to create a n by n matrix. The entries are  independent samples from real normal distribution with the mean 0 and standard deviation sqrt(n).

```
A=randn(n,n)/sqrt(n)
```

Can we predict the entries produced by the random generator will be in what range?

Can we define special properties for the matrices generated by randn(n,n)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sure, just remove elements that fall outside of your desired bounds. It wouldn't make sense for this to be an input to `randn` since that would make it no longer a normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. May be I did not explain my question well. A better way to ask is : Can we predict the generated numbers are in what range?

Comment: You can only define the percentage of points that will lie within a given range (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Empirical_Rule.PNG). With infinitely many points, *any* real number is a possible output.

Comment: I will look at it . Thank you.

Comment: Well, as you are using randn() you know for sure that you are generating random number following a normal pdf with default values of sigma=sqrt(n) and u=0. The range values are, in maths, -inf and +inf. In matlab, as you are using the default double, the range will be -MAX_DOUBLE and -MIN_DOUBLE. This, of course, for every random number generated. Which kind of "matrix-properties" are you looking for?

Comment: @Leos313 Thank you for your explanation. I was plotting the eigenvalues and spectral radius for such random matrices of different dimensions.Yet I cannot see an obvious trend in the plots.I saw  the matrix's entries  have small magnitude and I was trying to see if the properties of such a matrix affect the results.